# Porting a MySQL password query to Postgres

Tags: mysql, security, postgresql

I have a portion of a MySQL query which is designed to save a password using SHA512-CRYPT:

```
SELECT ENCRYPT('firstpassword', CONCAT('$6$', SUBSTRING(SHA(RAND()), -16)))
```

I need to port the application to use PostgreSQL, and as such, the statement is not compatible.
My attempt in PostgreSQL is like so:

```
SELECT CRYPT('firstpassword'::text, CONCAT('$6$', SUBSTRING(ENCODE(DIGEST(RANDOM()::text , 'sha1'), 'hex') FROM '.{16}$')))
```

When tested in component parts, each of these implementations appear identical, but as completed statements, the output differs.

I have found that the `CONCAT` statements (that generate the salt) appear to provide identical output.

If I try comparing the output of `CRYPT` or `ENCRYPT` using simple plaintext words, the output is identical. However, if I combine it with the output of a salt, the output differs;

MySQL:

```
SELECT ENCRYPT( 'firstpassword', '$6$ae73a5ca7d3e5b11' )
Produces: $6$ae73a5ca7d3e5b11$v/RbcEEx4VR37VMUF6gBnPNo2ptSyU...
```

PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT CRYPT('firstpassword'::text, '$6$ae73a5ca7d3e5b11'::text)
Produces: $6eTK2KpfoaQM
```

Can someone explain why these statements are diverging or suggest a better way to implement this MySQL query?

Answer (score 0):

They diverge because they use different encryption algorithms.

The first thing you want to do is to get very familiar with the pg_crypto documentation.  See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/pgcrypto.html

My suspicion is that you probably want to switch from something like encrypt/crypt to the use of SHA-2 for the actual password hashing so you can specifically control the algorithms and ensure compatibility on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

`SHA512-CRYPT` is not supported by PostgreSQL core or the `pgcrypto` extension shipped with the main sources. The `crypt` function shown in the question comes from `pgcrypto` and does only support bf, md5, des and xdes (see "supported algorithm" in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgcrypto.html)).

But you may use the [`shacrypt`](https://github.com/dverite/postgres-shacrypt) extension:

```
test=# create extension shacrypt ; -- (after installing from the sources)
CREATE EXTENSION

test=# select sha512_crypt('firstpassword', '$6$ae73a5ca7d3e5b11' );
                                                sha512_crypt                                                
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 $6$ae73a5ca7d3e5b11$v/RbcEEx4VR37VMUF6gBnPNo2ptSyU3ys1sg6i8hhBrcfBeLY6hpsfvXR67bwwjMainpPEaLkYV6eO0ow0xVH.
```

which gives the same result as MySQL's `SELECT ENCRYPT( 'firstpassword', '$6$ae73a5ca7d3e5b11' )`